# Git maintain two versions of the same code with only one commit diff

Tags: git

So, I have a web project, and the host url is hardcoded in it, I want to keep updating only one branch, and be able to get two different versions of the code, one for production (server domain) and one for testing (localhost).

I know there might be lots of ways to do it programatically, or even with a config file, or a script. but I was wondering if it can be done with git.

so for example.

```
master-> commit 1 -> commit 2 ..... -> HEAD
localhost/branch             -> commit x (where url is different) -> ... -> master head
```

so in this case localhost/branch was checked out of master after commit 2 and added commit x then kept tracking of master's HEAD, so every commit to master will update localhost/branch by fastforwarding it.

is there something like that ?

Comment: Why not just allow simple configuration of the host URL via an environment variable or command line option?

Comment: @JackManey I know it can be done 10 different ways, but I was wondering, because this feature can be useful for lots of small version variations in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Fast-forward is actually a label move thing, and is conditional on the "is ancestor" property: a label that moves from commit C<sub>old</sub> to C<sub>new</sub> has moved in a fast-forward fashion if and only if C<sub>old</sub> is an ancestor of C<sub>new</sub> (note that an identity move, i.e., when the two commit IDs are equal, can be considered a fast-forward, or can simply be ignored entirely since it's not actually a *move*).

In practical terms, since a commit ID's hash includes all its own ancestor IDs, if your "commit `x` on branch `localhost/branch`" is *not* present in the ancestry of the tip commit of branch `master`, then any new commit added to branch `master` cannot be a descendent of commit `x` until commit `x` is itself merged in.  **At this point you must either keep your configuration change** (so that `master` has the configuration change you do *not* want) **or discard your configuration change** (so that `master` differs as you wish it to).  Clearly you will choose the latter, but that means that, if you move the label `localhost/branch` to point to the same commit as the label `master`, then `localhost/branch` will also *not* contain this configuration change.

To put it more succinctly, in order to merge the branch you *will* give up the change made in `x`, and you *must* merge the branch in order to use fast-forward label moves.

Incidentally, this may make more sense if you draw your commit chains correctly.  They always point backward in time, not forward, and the labels point to the *newest*:

```
C1 <- C2 ... <- C8    <-- HEAD=master
          \
           Cx         <-- localhost/branch
```

All the arrow here point leftward (or left-and-up in the case of `Cx`).

Now if you add a new commit `C9` on to `master` (as pointed-to by `HEAD`):

```
C1 <- C2 ... <- C8 <- C9   <-- HEAD=master
          \
           Cx              <-- localhost/branch
```

Note that `Cx` is still not in `master`'s history chain, which now starts at `C9` and works back to `C1` and stops without ever including `Cx`.

You *can* (forcibly) change `localhost/branch` to point directly to `C9` but if you do, it no longer contains `Cx` either.

---

Should you wish to maintain this sort of thing, what you need to do is create a new merge commit (or as many as desired over time) stitching the `master` branch commits into the `localhost/branch` commits:

```
C1 <- C2 ... <- C8      <-- HEAD=master
          \ ...  \
           Cx ... C8x   <-- localhost/branch
```

and then:

```
C1 <- C2 ... <- C8 <- C9      <-- HEAD=master
          \ ...   \     \
           Cx ... C8x <- C9x  <-- localhost/branch
```

Note that commits `C8x` and `C9x` are not on branch `master` (starting at `C9` and working backwards, we cannot find them) but *are* on `localhost/branch`.  Note further that merging `C9` into `localhost/branch` (creating `C9x`) will apply the changes since the previous merge (of `C8` creating `C8x`) since the "merge base" (earliest common ancestor) is commit `C8`, and the only changes since `C8` are those in `C9`.

---

One key to really understanding git is to grok how *merging* `C9` into `localhost/branch` differs from *cherry-picking* `C9` into `localhost/branch`.  Both will do the exact same thing with the work-tree—both find the delta from `C8` to `C9` and apply that to `C8x`—but the *merge* records this in the new commit's history, by giving it two parent commit-IDs, while the cherry-pick does not (the new commit will have only one parent commit-ID).

(If that doesn't make sense right away, don't worry. :-)  If it *does* make sense, congratulations, you are really getting to know how git works.)

Comment: I understand what you're saying completely, and to be honest it was my expectation, but I was hoping that something I don't know would help, because it's a useful feature even though it appears to be technically impossible.

Anyway, It seems like it can be done via git hooks, where I execute a small script on the server after push that will merge master head with the localhost/branch, but unfortunately its not available on github.

Comment: You could certainly write hooks to automate this.  The main problem will probably be if a conflict occurs (if something "too close" to the change in `x` modifies the same lines).

Comment: Yeah I think I can write something to revert any merge if there was any conflict, and I can later fix the merge manually, but as I said github doesn't have that feature at all, so most likely I'll just use a script on the client side.